# Question about RLC circuit and struck in a problem, in the calculation getting current as infinity for the given values

Tags: current, passive-networks

[image]

Question about RLC circuit and struck in a problem, attached the photo related in the calculation getting current as infinity for the given values.any idea how to move forward

Comment: What happened to w (omega)?

Comment: @relayman357 It seems to be set to `1`

Comment: I see it now, eyes are getting old.

Answer (score 0):

So if the capacitive reactance magnitude exactly equals the inductive reactance, they cancel and the result is indeed zero impedance in that branch - making it a short circuit at that particular frequency.

Comment: Also, the current becomes trivial in this case. If the impedance is 0, Ir becomes 0 and the current through the first resistor, I, is just V(t)/1, or V(t).

Comment: You are correct sir. Was leaving that observation for the OP.

Comment: The current becomes infinite and the resistor current is irrelevant I think he meant to say.

Comment: No, I think he is just saying that the dead short prevents any current through parallel resistor.  It is not infinite current, because of the series resistor.  VA in his case is zero at this frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Just consider the capacitor and inductance in series: -

$$Z = \dfrac{1}{j\omega C} + j\omega L = j\omega L - j\dfrac{1}{j\omega C}$$

And when this happens...

$$\omega L = \dfrac{1}{\omega C}$$

...the net series impedance becomes zero at this frequency: -

$$\omega = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}$$

Comment: I think you meant to drop that denominator j term at far right of your top equation and skipped over it.

Comment: Oops yeah you’re right.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting infinite current is that you're modeling an ideal voltage source driving a short at the resonant frequency.  That would result in infinite current.  What you need to do is take into account the other (series) resistor, which will limit the current through the short.